# Performance wise: is it better to use inner join or open new connection/another query

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I have 2 tables like this:

Table A:

```
article_id | attribute_id
1          | 5
2          | 6
```

Table B:

```
attribute_id | attribute_name
5            | foo
6            | bar
```

I would like to get the result:

```
article_id | attribute_id | attribute_name
1          | 5            | foo
```

I have 2 solution:
Solution A:
 either to use inner join like this:

```
SELECT TableA.article_id, TableB.*
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.attribute_id = TableB.attribute_id
WHERE TableA.article_id = 1
```

Or Solution B, In my Java program:

- to query first in Table A.
- open new connection, and query in Table B using "article_id" from first query.

I would like to know performance wise, which solution is better. 
Please, notice, Table A, and B will receive massive amount of hits. also, notice, I'm using mysql and tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join is magnitudes faster, because a new connection has quite some overhead.

Answer (score 4):

This is almost always a "try it with your real data and see which works better" thing.

In *general*, I'd expect the join to be more efficient (much more). But again, you have to try it with *your* data and *your* setup.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: the join.

Long answer: if you are **very** concerned with performance, I'd say create an indexed view based on the join, and select on it.